# How would you write this set of linear programming problems as latex?

Tags: equations, alignment

I am not able to make myself understood over at Mathematics Stackexchange in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3269997/8530).

Therefore I ask here the Latex experts how to write these linear programming problems as latex, the standard way of communicating mathematics at the stack exchange network:

**Linear programming problem written in Mathematica 8.0:**

```
(*start*)
nn = 18;
TableForm[
  L2 = Table[
    LinearProgramming[
     Table[1/n, {n, 1, k}], {Table[If[n == 1, k, 1], {n, 1, k}]}, {{1,
        0}}, Table[
      If[n == 1, {-1, 1}, {-2 (n - 1), 0 (n - 1)}], {n, 1, k}]], {k, 
     1, nn}]]
(*end*)
```

Here is my own try:

```
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{x_{n}}{n} \\ 
\text{subject to constraints:} & k + \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{n=k}x_{n}=1 \\ 
& x_1 \geq -1 \end{array}$$

for all $k$ and for all $n>1:$
$$-2(n-1) \leq x_n \leq 0 \tag{4}$$
```

[image]
For some reason the latex above does not parse here on the Latex site. Maybe someone can edit appropriately, before I find it out myself how to write latex here?

Comment: to show latex output, clip a screenshot of your pdf viewer and upload the image.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200836/328

Comment: Yes they run MathJax on the mathematica site but it is not enabled here as it would be confusing as we need to see tex output.

Comment: I added a screen shot

Comment: Are you asking how to write this in latex or are you asking how to write this in mathjax, which is used on math.se

Comment: What should be changed in the output?

Comment: I just need something that is mathematically valid and is in agreement with the Mathematica program. It is a translation job really.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html

Comment: I think translating from mathematica is off topic, what is on topic (and was how your question is most naturally read) is asking how to use latex to layout a particular constrained problem in an acceptable way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dedicated package for optimisation problems: `optidef`. Does this befit you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{3}
\begin{mini}
{x}{\sum_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{x_{n}}{n}}{\label{mylinpb}}{}
\addConstraint{ k + \sum_{n=2}^{n=k}x_{n}=1}{}{\quad\text{forall }k}
\addConstraint{x_1\ge 1}{}
\addConstraint{-2(n-1) \le x_n \le 0}{}{\quad\text{forall }n > 1.}
\end{mini}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you translate this from the Mathematica program above? I am not used to the topics at tex stack exchange. What I am looking for is a latexification of the Mathematica program.

Comment: NO, I mad it from scratch. Never used Mathematica. Doesn't Mathematice have  a tool to convert its programs into LaTeX code?

Comment: Unfortunately not. They give examples though in the documentation how to translate specific cases, but not in general. Or at least I have not understood the documentation yet. For other commands such as sums and products used in calculus the translation is automatic. I am using version 8.0 of Mathematica.